# Visualizing Parse tree - nested list to tree in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, tree, data-visualization

I have the output of CYK Parsing as a nested list :

```
parser.parse('the dog saw the man with the telescope')

Out :
["S", ["NP", ["DT", "the"], ["NN", "dog"]], ["VP", ["Vt", "saw"], ["NP", ["NP", ["DT", "the"], ["NN", "man"]], ["PP", ["P", "with"], ["NP", ["DT", "the"], ["NN", "telescope"]]]]]]
```

Could someone please tell me how to convert this nested list into a Tree that can be easily interpreted ? Something like this :

[image]

How do I achieve this in Python or using any other external libraries ? Could someone please help me ?

Comment: What should happen with`["NN", "dog"]`?

Comment: Well yes , I want a complete visualization of the Parse Tree, from the top POS tags up to the words in the leaf nodes . I just gave a small example in the question

Comment: Yes, but how do they fit in the Tree?

Comment: I have edited my question to show an example . Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [treelib](https://treelib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), in the following fashion:

```
from treelib import Node, Tree


lst = ["S", ["NP", ["DT", "the"], ["NN", "dog"]], ["VP", ["Vt", "saw"], ["NP", ["NP", ["DT", "the"], ["NN", "man"]],
                                                                   ["PP", ["P", "with"],
                                                                    ["NP", ["DT", "the"], ["NN", "telescope"]]]]]]

root, *tail = lst
tree = Tree()
node = Node(root)
tree.add_node(node)

q = [[node, *tail]]
while q:
    parent, *children = q.pop()
    for child in children:
        if isinstance(child, list):
            head, *tail = child
            node = tree.create_node(head, parent=parent)
            q.append([node, *tail])
        else:
            tree.create_node(child, parent=parent)

tree.show()
```

**Output**

```
S
├── NP
│   ├── DT
│   │   └── the
│   └── NN
│       └── dog
└── VP
    ├── NP
    │   ├── NP
    │   │   ├── DT
    │   │   │   └── the
    │   │   └── NN
    │   │       └── man
    │   └── PP
    │       ├── NP
    │       │   ├── DT
    │       │   │   └── the
    │       │   └── NN
    │       │       └── telescope
    │       └── P
    │           └── with
    └── Vt
        └── saw
```